# Eclipse - Public instance methods

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse by which I can find all the public/protected/private instance methods of all the classes in a project?

Answer (score 0):

Select the project (or projects) you want to search in. Select the *Search* > *Java*... menu item. Enter * as the search string and configure the other params as you want. For example, this should find all methods declared in the project:
[image]

Comment: This will find the method with the name. I would like to find it based on visibility of the methods.